# Hosting ASP.Net MVC 4 SPA web Application in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4, publish, web-hosting, singlepage

I am having my application in [ASP.NET MVC 4 SPA.](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application)
It was developed using the template in Visual Studio 2012 after installing [Web-tools 2012.2.](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application)
But after my work when I tried to host it in IIS after publishing it to a local folder, I am getting the directory listing missing error.
I have also tried with normal ASP.NET SPA, the result is same.
Tried to specify the default document option as well but not helping.
Debug works fine and able to get output.
I installed IIS on my development machine and tried but stuck at the same place now.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 SPA and Entity Framework 5.0.0.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the bin deployable assemblies feature for the MVC assemblies?

Comment: @MarkG - MVC4 is always bin-deployed

Comment: Good point - forgot about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it resolved. Need to copy the Services(DLL) folder in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install IIS after MVC? If so, you'll need to register ASP.NET with IIS. Open a VS command prompt and type `aspnet_regiis -i` - see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx