# User in Web Site Administration Tool on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, website-admin-tool

I'm new in ASP and IIS and I trying to solve this problem for 2 days but still can't get it.at 1st, I created a ASP login page and the user information store in Web Site Administration Tool (VS2008 Project>ASP.NET Configuration) It works fine as I can log in to my aspx page when I debug it.


Next, I turn on the window feature `(IIS under item World Wide Web Services >> Application Development Features all are selected except CGI)`


Then, I publish my login page and go to ***C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config*** add few lines

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="connect" connectionString="Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=school;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;IntegratedSecurity=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|ASPNETDB.MDF;User Instance=true" name="ConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ptiConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|pti.mdf;IntegratedSecurity=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

</connectionStrings>
```

Next, I open up IIS Manager enable ASP.NET Impersonation and i try to browse to localhost and I still unable to access to my login page

I also enable Form Authentication but still the same , can't login. Can Anyone help me ??

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you enabled forms authentication in web.config?

Comment: yes i have enable forms authentication....but there is no error message

Comment: I just can't login to my page...it seem it does have my user login information

Comment: Can you access any other pages on the site? If you create a static html page, can you access that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install IIS after you installed ASP.NET? If so, you'll need to register ASP.NET with IIS - see my answer here: [Hosting ASP.Net MVC 4 SPA web Application in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117602/hosting-asp-net-mvc-4-spa-web-application-in-iis/14118863#14118863)

Comment: after i type "aspnet_regiis -i", i got another problem HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error ; Error code : 0x800700b7

Comment: What's the rest of that error message? You've probably got an error in your web.config file somewhere. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0

Comment: Module IIS Web Core<br/>
Notification Unknown<br/>
Handler Not yet determined<br/>
Error Code 0x800700b7<br/>
Config Error There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined<br/>
Config File \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config<br/>
Requested URL http://localhost:80/<br/>
Physical Path <br/>
Logon Method Not yet determined<br/>
Logon User Not yet determined<br/>

Comment: There's your answer: There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined

Comment: Well, if there's a duplicate system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler section, you need to look in your web.config file and remove the duplicate entry. Maybe you have 2 system.web.extensions sections or duplication within that section

Comment: Hmm, looks ok to me - looks like you're using asp.net 3.5 - which version of the framework is the IIS application pool running under? If you're using 3.5, the framework version needs to be 2.0

Comment: I have make some changes on the Application Pool...set DefaultAppPool to v2.0 .Net framework<br/>I can browse to localhost again but I still can login to the page